# Qt access viewer object in every class?

Tags: c++, qt, qprogressbar

I have a progress bar object (ui->QprogressBar) available in my mainwindow.cpp. But, I want to use this object in another class (readerfile.cpp).

Headers

mainwindow.h

demo.h

Sources

mainwindow.cpp

demo.cpp

I use this method to call object most of the time:- Using a function call, for example -mainwindow.cpp I will call this function

```
mainwindow->isFunction(ui->QprogressBar);
```

isFunction is available inside my demo.cpp file

```
void demo :: isfunction (QProgressBar *progress)
```

But, Now I want to use QprogressBar object directly inside my demo.cpp file.
I tried all possible combinations, connections and just can't get it work.
So could someone please explain me, how to access UI elements object from class demo.

Any idea for the solution will be a great help.
Thanks.

Comment: What problem are you getting when passing the object to a function? can you post some code to clarify the issue?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a moment to read about [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Apologies, but I am having a rather hard time understanding your question (I tried to edit it, but had to give up when I got totally lost half-way through). Can you rephrase what exactly you want to do and what you are having problems with?

Comment: Please, spent some time to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) as well.

Comment: The Qt solution is to use signals and slots instead of pass pointers around to widgets. Put a slot on your main window to change the progress value. Emit a signal from your readerfile object that is connected to the slot in you have added to your main window.

Comment: I have added new point . Just check it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a pointer to an object from another class you need to implement a public function that returns this pointer. I will give you a little example:

Your class `MainWindow` in the header file will include a function `progressbar()`.

`mainwindow.h`:

```
//...
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
   Q_ObBJECT
public:
   QProgressBar *progressbar();   //returns a pointer to the QProgressBar
   //..
private:
   //..
};
```

This function is implemented in `mainwindow.cpp` like this:

```
QProgressBar *MainWindow::progressbar()
{
return ui->progbar;    //I just called it like this to avoid confusion, it's the just the name you defined using QtDesigner
}
```

Then, in `demo.hpp` if you have an instance of `MainWindow` in your class:

```
//..
class Demo : public QObject
{
   Q_OBJECT
public:
   //..
private:
   MainWindow *window;
   //..
}
```

you can just access `QProgressBar` using by calling the function in `demo.cpp`:

```
QProgressBar *bar;
bar = window->progressbar();
```

---

I have to say though that it's unusual to have an instance of `MainWindow` in another class. Usually your `QMainWindow` or `QApplication` is the main entry point to the program and you have instances of the other classes in them, not the other way around.

Comment: this one progressbar (ui->progbar) and this one (QProgressBar *bar;
bar = window->progressbar(); ) both are same

Comment: yes, progbar is in the mainwindow class and bar is the same object but in the demo class, which is what you wanted if I understood correctly.

Comment: every calculation I am calculating inside the demo.cpp file. so i just pass the (ui->QprogressBar) over demo.cpp. ui->QprogressBar->setMinimum(0);
 ui->QprogressBar->setMaximum(100); ui->QprogressBar->setValue(i);, I want to use all the 3 method inside the demo.cpp file not inside the mainwindow.cpp

Comment: yes. If you do what I wrote, you can do this by calling bar->setMinimum(0), bar->setValue(i), bar->setMaximum(100). Just try it.

Comment: Actually this one getting error for me QProgressBar *bar;
bar = window->progressbar();

Comment: I am getting exception violation in this line QProgressBar *MainWindow::progressbar()
{
return ui->progbar;   
}

Comment: what kind of exception? and access violation? does progbar exist as part of the ui in qt designer?

Comment: just see the image view of vilation

Comment: you cannot write ui->QProgressBar. This is not correct. As I said either define the progress bar in Designer and give it a name or declare it in the constructor of MainWindow, if you are doing it in code. and the use the name as ui->thenameyouchoseforqprogressbar